# Possible use of choice in proving "Compactness implies limit point compactness"

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, compactness, axiom-of-choice

A standard proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2554988/a-step-in-a-proof-that-compactness-implies-limit-point-compactness). Basically, the idea is to prove the contrapositive:

> Let $A\subseteq X$. If $X$ is compact and $A$ doesn't have any limit
>   point, then A is finite.

Since A has no limit points, for each $a\in A$, there exists a neighboorhood $U_a$ such that $U_a\cap A =
\{a\}$. $\{X-A\}\cup\{U_a:a\in A\}$ forms an open cover of $X$. By
compactness of $X$, only finitely many covers $X$. Because $X-A$ and $A$ are disjoint, A must be finite.

However, the above proof seems to rely on the axiom of choice, since we need to choose a neighborhood $U_a$ for each $a \in A$, and there isn't any definite way to do so.

So can somebody clarify whether AC is necessary here? If not needed, please provide an alternative proof. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some authors who find using the AC a bit too much tend to present proofs only for separable and metrizable spaces. In those cases, you can avoid using the AC by an inductive argument. However, AC is absolutely necessary whenever you take infinitely many elements of a set and you do not provide a function explicitly. That is to say, in general topological settings, either you lose lots of results or you accept the AC imo.

Comment: Indeed it is.  Topology is definitely pro-choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not require the Axiom of Choice.

For every $a\in A$, set
$$
\mathcal W_a=\big\{U\subset X: U \,\text{open}\,\,\&\,\,U\cap A=\{a\} \big\}
$$
clearly $\mathcal W_a\ne\varnothing$ and its definition DOES NOT require the Axiom of Choice.

Then set $U_a=\bigcup \mathcal W_a$.

Now, $\mathcal W=\{U_a: a\in A\}$ is a cover without a finite subcover, and it is defined without appealing to the AC.

Comment: "Its definition does require the Axiom of choice." You mean without AC, $\mathcal W_a$ cannot be formed, right?

Comment: Or you are intended to mean "doesn't"?

Comment: @YuiToCheng Thanx! - I corrected my answer

Comment: Thanks, that's a perfect answer.

Comment: You do need to remark that $A$ is closed and hence itself compact to complete the contradiction. Or like the OP add its complement to the cover.